# Amazon RDS for PostgreSQL DB with SSL Authentication?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-rds, pgadmin-4

I have a postgres SQL DB instance created on AWS RDS. I would like to connect to the postgres DB instance over ssl from my pgAdmin 4 tool which is installed on my local machine.

How do we sign the certificates a client cert against AWS's root cert so that it can be used for connection where you know the connection is secure (ssl). I could see the below config details on my AWS RDS postgres DB instance, but I couldn't download them or see a way to download those certs.

`ssl_ca_file = /rdsdbdata/rds-metadata/ca-cert.pem ssl_cert_file = /rdsdbdata/rds-metadata/server-cert.pem ssl_key_file = /rdsdbdata/rds-metadata/server-key.pem`

how to connect and what certificates or keys should I give in the Client Cert, Client cert key, root cert, cert revocation list locations in the attached screen shot?

Answer (score 0):

Amazon PostgreSQL RDS does not support client certs.  So you connect over SSL to verify the server to the client, and to get encryption, but not to verify the client/user to the server.  You still use passwords (generally) to do that.